# Is it possible to create a 2D array of stacks?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, stack

I am quite new to java and this is also my first question on StackOverflow. I am trying to create a game where a board, represented by a `5x5` 2D array, can have a maximum of 4 chips stacked on each grid square.

```java
import java.util.Stack;
public class Trying {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // How would I get these stacks..
        Stack<String> stackR1C1 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR1C2 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR1C3 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR1C4 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR2C1 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR2C2 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR2C3 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR2C4 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR3C1 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR3C2 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR3C3 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR3C4 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR4C1 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR4C2 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR4C3 = new Stack<>();
        Stack<String> stackR4C4 = new Stack<>();
        // Into this 2D array
        String[][] boardArray = {
                {"   ", "c1 ", "c2 ", "c3 ", "c4 "},
                {"r1 ", "__|", "__|", "__|", "__|"},
                {"r2 ", "__|", "__|", "__|", "__|"},
                {"r3 ", "__|", "__|", "__|", "__|"},
                {"r4 ", "__|", "__|", "__|", "__|"}};
    }
}
```

When I try to simply add the stacks into their positions in the array I get this error:

```
error: incompatible types: Stack<String> cannot be converted to String
```

Comment: Yes, but you need to store them in an array of the right type: `Stack<String>[][]`, rather than `String[][]`. With that said, arrays and generics don't play well together, so you should consider using a `List<List<Stack<String>>>` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You said that `boardArray` was an array of string-arrays, not an array of `Stack<>()`.

After declaring the array *properly,* write a simple nested-loop to fill it with `new Stack<>()`